# Python 3 and Tkinter- how to control a quiz loop

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, tkinter

I'm sure the answer to this is obvious but I cannot spot it! I have a very basic quiz(using Tkinter and Python 3) which uses 2 arrays , the question is displayed and then the answer entered is matched using the array index when the submit button is clicked.

1. The question at index 0 is displayed twice- cannot see why
2. The score does not increment correctly- even though it is a global variable- it just shows 1 each time.
3. How can I get the quiz to move to a print statement after the end of the list is reached?

I have tried putting an IF statement in the submit function to check the value of i but cannot get this to work. Can anyone point out my errors please?

```
from tkinter import *

global questions
questions =["What is the name of the Simpsons' next door neighbour?","What is the name of the    school bus driver?",
        "Who runs the Kwik-e-mart?","What does Bart do at the end of the opening credits?"]
global answers
answers = [ "Ned Flanders","Otto","Apu","Write On The Blackboard"]

global score
score = 0
global i
i = 0




def submit():
    '''runs the submit button'''
    global i
    global score

    question.config(text=questions[i])
    if answer.get().lower()==answers[i].lower():
        score+=1
    else:
        score=score
    i+=1

    scoretxt.config(text =str(score))
    answer.delete(0,END)


window = Tk()
window.title("Simpsons Quiz")
window.wm_iconbitmap("homer.ico")
window.configure(background ="#ffd600")

banner = PhotoImage(file ="the-simpsons-banner.gif")
Label(window,image = banner).grid(row = 0,columnspan = 6)
Label(window,text = "Question : ",bg ="#ffd600",justify=LEFT).grid(row = 1,column = 0)
Label(window,text = "Type answer here: ",bg = "#ffd600",justify=LEFT).grid(row = 3, column = 0)
scoreLabel =Label(window,bg = "#ffd600")
scoretxt = Label(window,text ="Your score is: ?",bg = "#ffd600")
scoreLabel.grid(row=5,column = 2)
scoretxt.grid(row = 6,column = 2)
question=Label(window,bg = "white",text= questions[0],justify=LEFT)
question.grid(row =1,column=1)
answer = Entry(window,bg ="white",width = 30)
answer.grid(row = 3,column=1)

# make a submit button

Button(window,text= "Submit",bg = "white",command = submit).grid(row = 3,column = 2)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You are printing the question before you increment `i`. That's why you get twice.
2) It is always 1 becuase of your usage of `global`. In python you use `global` keyword in which scope you want to change your variable. Sadly, my english is not good enough to explain this. Please check out [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python).
3) You can use [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions) block. I used it there because that is the exact line where you get the error. You can expand its range.

```
from tkinter import *

questions =["What is the name of the Simpsons' next door neighbour?","What is the name of the    school bus driver?",
        "Who runs the Kwik-e-mart?","What does Bart do at the end of the opening credits?"]

answers = [ "Ned Flanders","Otto","Apu","Write On The Blackboard"]

#removed globals from here
score = 0
i = 0

def submit():
    '''runs the submit button'''
    global i
    global score

    if answer.get().lower()==answers[i].lower():
        score+=1

    i+=1 #first increment, then show the question since you already show it at startup

    try:  #since you get the IndexError on this line, I used on here
        question.config(text=questions[i])
    except IndexError:
        print ("something")

    scoretxt.config(text = "Your score is: {}".format(str(score)))
    answer.delete(0,END)


window = Tk()
window.title("Simpsons Quiz")
window.wm_iconbitmap("homer.ico")
window.configure(background ="#ffd600")

banner = PhotoImage(file ="the-simpsons-banner.gif")
Label(window,image = banner).grid(row = 0,columnspan = 6)
Label(window,text = "Question : ",bg ="#ffd600",justify=LEFT).grid(row = 1,column = 0)
Label(window,text = "Type answer here: ",bg = "#ffd600",justify=LEFT).grid(row = 3, column = 0)
scoreLabel =Label(window,bg = "#ffd600")
scoretxt = Label(window,text ="Your score is: ?",bg = "#ffd600")
scoreLabel.grid(row=5,column = 2)
scoretxt.grid(row = 6,column = 2)
question=Label(window,bg = "white",text= questions[0],justify=LEFT)
question.grid(row =1,column=1)
answer = Entry(window,bg ="white",width = 30)
answer.grid(row = 3,column=1)

# make a submit button

Button(window,text= "Submit",bg = "white",command = submit).grid(row = 3,column = 2)

mainloop()
```

Also you might want to use a dictionary instead of questions-answers lists.

Comment: Thanks very much! I can now see why I wasn't getting anywhere.